How to use Library that works on Java version 17, in my Java version 8 project?
I can't use spring-snapshots library in my project.
I'm going to develop simple chat function using Azure OpenAI and this is guide URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/chatgpt-quickstart?tabs=command-line%2Cpython-new&pivots=programming-language-spring ( Now project works on Java version 8. )
This example works on Java version 17 and I have following issue:
And this is pom.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.honghukeji</groupId>
    <artifactId>hhkj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hhkj</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental.ai</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ai-azure-openai-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 数据库-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>at.favre.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JWT-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.74</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 分页插件 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.pagehelper</groupId>
            <artifactId>pagehelper</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qiniu</groupId>
            <artifactId>qiniu-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 腾讯云短信-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tencentcloudapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>tencentcloud-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.270</version><!-- 注：这里只是示例版本号（可直接使用），可获取并替换为 最新的版本号，注意不要使用4.0.x版本（非最新版本） -->
        </dependency>
        <!--腾讯云存储 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qcloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>cos_api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qcloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>cos-sts_api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--阿里OSS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aliyun.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>aliyun-sdk-oss</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 腾讯云IM签名-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tencentyun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tls-sig-api-v2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
            <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  视频处理      视频获取每一帧-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2-1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency >
            <groupId >com.sun.mail</groupId >
            <artifactId >javax.mail</artifactId >
            <version >1.6.0</version >
        </dependency >
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alipay.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>alipay-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.39.110.ALL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkout-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add spring-core dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- 设置一些没有编译的文件 -->
        <resources>
            <!-- java文件夹下只编译java文件， xml文件没有进行编译。在此指定需要编译的xml文件位置 -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <!--<filtering>true</filtering>-->
            </resource>
            <!-- maven打jar包时没有将resources编译，在此指定进行编译 -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html -->
                <!--<filtering>false</filtering>-->
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--添加配置跳过测试-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--添加配置跳过测试-->
        </plugins>

    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

I want to use this spring-snapshots in Java version 8.

If there's access to the source code, you could try compiling it in Java 8 and reverting code that's been written with syntax structures that didn't exist in Java 8 to work in Java 8.

I want to use this spring-snapshots in Java version 8: this will not work. The people writing that code use Java 17 language features and accordingly compile their code for Java 17. I don't think they are going to rewrite their code just for you.

Please read: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Note that rewriting might be possible but would be a big task since their source code uses newer language features like switch expressions, records and text blocks - and these are only the features that were easy to find. They probably also use newer classes from the Java core libraries (no examples provided because these are harder to find)
