How to implement Azure openai in Java version 8 project
As I mentioned before, now I have trouble using spring-snapshot library in Java version 8 project. I think the reason is this library was launched after Java version 8. (Java version 8 was launched over 10 years ago)
Currently this library works on Java 17 and this is tutorial URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/dall-e-quickstart?tabs=dalle3%2Ccommand-line&pivots=programming-language-java
If so, is it impossible that implement Azure openai in Java version 8 project? If it's possible, please let me know how to do.
I'd like to implement Azure openai feature in my Java version 8 project.

You already asked the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78694273/how-to-use-library-that-works-on-java-version-17-in-my-java-version-8-project. Please don't duplicate questions.

This question is similar to: How to use Library that works on Java version 17, in my Java version 8 project?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use rest api if the library is not supporting in java 8.
